# Conditional breakpoint strange affects to the code running

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging

I have two loops, one is nested. And this code just shifting data chunks in memory. When I set a breakpoint to catch when there are incorrect addresses, it almost stopes the loop and it starts running very slow(> 1 min). I tried to store addresses values in variables and then just compare them in breakpoint: ad1 != ad2 || ad3 != ad4. But it still slows down the code and for some reason the list size is changing to a huge value. When I'm turning off the breakpoint it goes fine.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to [Bowman Zhu-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6261890/bowman-zhu-msft) for sharing [MSDN link to VS debugger docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/debugger/visual-studio-debugger-extensibility). In quick read I found that [to calculate the expression of a conditional breakpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/debugger/evaluating-expressions), debugger needs:

1. Parse the expression string.
2. Evaluate the parsed token(There are sync and async methods).

And the reason why the conditional breakpoint calculating is long - is because these steps runs every time when the debugger hits the breakpoint. As I understood, the parsed result is not caching, because you can change the expression in runtime and it needs parse the expression every single time. And it will slow down your application running if you set the cond. breakpoint in critical code(e.g. loops with thousands iterations). Just use code pattern showed in [Grigore's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76972261/12505528).

Answer (score 1):

Conditional breakpoints are expensive in time-critical code. I suggest you move the check in code and outside the breakpoint, and set the breakpoint inside the if.

So :

```
if (ad1 != ad2){
    // Statement on which you break
}
```

The statement can be a printf so it doesn't get optimized away.

Comment: What I actually do. But I'm still interesting why any condition breakpoint in exactly one place in the code has such behavior. In another loops with this job it works good.

Comment: @Fun Are both lopps called as frequently? If it's just one call per second, it won't be noticeable, if it's hundreds or thousands, it will. The breakpoint check isn't as cheap as a check in code, an interrupt is inserted in the executable and the debugger checks the values, unlike executing a simple cmp on the processor.

Comment: I checked the iteration count of all these loops and find that it's actually a big value. So yea, in this case the condition breakpoint is affecting to the runtime. But can you tell me where I can read about how conditional breakpoint is calculating by debugger? I thought that the "price" of con. breakpoint depends on conditional expression length - the shorter the faster , but it's wrong as I found.